# Pig script parameters in Hue editor

Tags: apache-pig, hue

Im writing a pig script in Hue pig editor, but when executing it, it says that there is EOF at column 3:
[image]

This happens when i use parameters or through `%declare` or `%default`, and the same scripts work fine using `$pig myscript.pig` command. 
I use Hue 3.7.0.

Comment: I've stumble upon this as well. I think it's simply a bug in Hue.

Comment: @LiMuBei I also think that is a bug, but may be we can find a workaround.

Comment: Maybe with some weird escaping?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [HUE-2508](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2508) that was fixed in [Hue 3.9](http://gethue.com/hue-3-9-is-out/).